# Define database and table name for validator

Tags: php, database, laravel, validation

Usually this is the method we used to validate input from our users

```
$rules = array(
        'username'  => 'required|between:3,32|alpha_dash',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|min:6',
    );
```

But i'm facing a problem here. I'm using the other database for the user, while i want to validate both username and email should be unique through this portion of code. May i know what should i do to make this

```
unique:users
```

know which database and table to dig and validate? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to define your own validation rule to make this happen. You'll probably want to register a rule to validate uniqueness in a different database. [This page](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) has documentation on registering your own validation rules. You can either call the `Validator::register` method or extend the Validator class.

Inside your rule, you'll just have to query the database looking for a row with that email. Validation passes if it's null and fails otherwise.